# Are Read-Only Properties in Javascript Objects REALLY Read-Only?

Tags: javascript

I know that it's possible to create a read-only object in Javascript with code similar to this (sorry, "borrowed it" from another thread):

```
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty( obj, "<yourPropertyNameHere>", {
  value: "<yourPropertyValueHere>",
  writable: false,
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true
});
```

But as a Java developer, I know that I can use reflection to change a field that is declared as private. What I need to know is this: is it possible to prevent a malicious end-user from changing a read-only variable declared in the manner above?

Edit: Okay, I get it. This was a component of, not the entirety of, an entire security infrastructure. All inputs from the client-side to the server-side will be validated at the server side (I'm not a total idiot). But I want to explore the possibility of doing SOMETHING to make the client aware of the backend security infrastructure (roles assigned, etc).

Comment: There is no way to do that, the malicious user controls the whole environment. Even if you manage that they can just modify the code.

Comment: Why do you care about how a malicious end-user manipulates the contents of her browser's own memory? Once it's in the client, you've lost the game. **Read-only variables are not a security feature.**

Comment: Um... are you running end-supplied code, and attempting to secure it using read-only properties?  That is... a bad idea.

Comment: No. The backend code uses Spring Security with X.509 certificate based authentication, and any input from client-side will be validated. However, being able to generate some sort of token would allow us to leverage a modern Javascript framework, while taking advantage of the existing security infrastructure.

Comment: What's with the downvotes guys? This is a legitimate question about the nature of read-only in JavaScript as compared to the read-only nature of Java.

Answer (score 2):

This question has only one answer, never trust js. Even thought you can declare it, there is no way to be sure the user won't change the hole object.
The way to avoid the user tampering with your variables is using closure. Just define a function, declare all your variables, and run that function. There is a shorthand for that:

```
(function () {
    //Your code, DECLARE ALL YOUR VARIABLES WITH "var variableName"
    //i.e.
    var myNumber = 3, myString = 'Hello World', myEmptyVar;
})();
```

Take a look at 'use strict' (strict mode) and use jshint for better coding